# How can I implement an ASP.NET Core middleware to remove instances of repeated slashes in a request URL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In the previous version of ASP.NET MVC, URLs like the following were tolerated: `https://www.trap.com//house`.

[Now, this generates a `404`, which makes sense in a way.](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/980) I like that by default ASP.NET Core MVC now is less tolerant of nonsense in general.

But I am left wondering how to go about the suggestion of implementing a middleware to address the issue. [I found this example](https://github.com/mikaelm12/Canonical-Url-Middleware/blob/master/Middleware/CanonicalUrlMiddleware.cs), but I don't want to *redirect* the user to the "right" or canonical URL - I want to tolerate the bad one.

In other words, I want the URL `https://www.trap.com//house` to be routed as though it were the URL `https://www.trap.com/house`. Or the URL `https://www.trap.com///house/////4` to be routed as though it were the URL `https://www.trap.com/house/4`.

What is the best way to achieve this? URL rewriting? Special routes? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way of course is to fix the applications sending incorrect URLs.  In light of that not likely happening, I would suggest adding some URL rewrite rules that handle these before the url is handed off to MVC.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using the rewrite middleware to accomplish this, although I will probably end up removing it...

```
        var rewriteOptions = new RewriteOptions()
            .AddRewrite("^///?(.*)$", "/$1", false)
            .AddRewrite("^///?(.*)///?(.*)$", "/$1/$2", false); //etc, maybe you could make a regex that catches all these patterns
        app.UseRewriter(rewriteOptions);
```

Comment: This ended up being the right solution for me. The only caveat I would add is to make sure `app.UseMvc();` comes **after** this.